Dynamically Generating HTML Links with Dialogflow CX Datastore Handlers
Purpose:
We are using the Datastore handler in Dialogflow CX to generate responses to user queries. The Datastore contains HTML files. Is it possible for the agent to provide the URL of an embedded link within the HTML as part of its response?
Input Type: Text
I conducted a test to determine if the Dialogflow CX agent was capable of generating responses containing embedded HTML links in the chat interface.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This is not possible at least with datastore. If you can share some details. I can provide some guidance.

In a data store, RAG (Retrieval-Augmented Generation) serves as a solution for implementing advanced retrieval and generation tasks. You can utilize services like Cloud Run or Cloud Functions to deploy custom RAG implementations using tools such as LangChain, Python, Gemini, and vector search techniques within the retrieval process. By mapping appropriate links and structuring a well-defined solution, you can achieve highly descriptive and functional outcomes. However, proficient knowledge of Python is essential to execute this effectively.
1.https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/rags-powered-by-google-search-technology-part-1
